# "any other" + singular / plural

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct, and could you please tell me why?

> She is more popular than any other singers/singer in the USA.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> She is more popular than any other singer in the USA.

"Any other" can be used with both singular and plural nouns, but in this case, you have to use singular, "singer", as the use of "more popular than" *and* "any other" suggests the use of singular noun.

E.g.

> She is more popular than him

Comment: Please explain why *"more popular than" suggests the use of singular noun*. After all, I could surely write: *I am more popular than my brothers.*

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Am I correct to say that the use of both "more popular than" and "any other" suggests a singular noun?

Comment: I don't think so: *My brother and I are more popular than any other brothers on the planet.*

Answer (score 0):

*Any other* implies 'any one other'. There is no individual singer in the USA more popular than she is.

If you wish to use the plural, you need to leave out *any.*

> She is more popular than [all the] other singers in the USA.